Problem creating a Drawable instance in compose
I need to migrate my old java code that creates a Drawable instance which is a gradient with a starting color in the upper part and a finishing color in the bottom part.
It worked perfectly in java, but after migrating the code to kotlin and compose, getDrawable function returns an empty transparent drawable:
override fun getDrawable(): Drawable {
    val sf: ShaderFactory = object : ShaderFactory() {
        override fun resize(width: Int, height: Int): Shader {
            return LinearGradient(
                startX(width), startY(height), endX(width), endY(height), intArrayOf(
                    color1, color2
                ),
                null, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR
            )
        }
    }
    val p = PaintDrawable()
    p.shape = RectShape()
    p.shaderFactory = sf
    return p
}
   
fun startX(actualWidth: Int): Float {
    when (type) {
        Type.SOLID -> return 0f
        Type.DEGREE_DOWN_UP, Type.DEGREE_UP_DOWN -> return actualWidth / 2.0f
        Type.DEGREE_LEFT_RIGHT -> return 0.0f
        Type.DEGREE_RIGHT_LEFT -> return actualWidth.toFloat()
        else -> {}
    }
    return (-1).toFloat()
}

fun startY(actualHeight: Int): Float {
    when (type) {
        Type.SOLID -> return 0f
        Type.DEGREE_DOWN_UP -> return actualHeight.toFloat()
        Type.DEGREE_LEFT_RIGHT, Type.DEGREE_RIGHT_LEFT -> return actualHeight / 2.0f
        Type.DEGREE_UP_DOWN -> return 0f
        else -> {}
    }
    return (-1).toFloat()
}

fun endX(actualWidth: Int): Float {
    when (type) {
        Type.SOLID -> return actualWidth.toFloat()
        Type.DEGREE_DOWN_UP, Type.DEGREE_UP_DOWN -> return actualWidth / 2.0f
        Type.DEGREE_LEFT_RIGHT -> return actualWidth.toFloat()
        Type.DEGREE_RIGHT_LEFT -> return 0f
        else -> {}
    }
    return (-1).toFloat()
}

fun endY(actualHeight: Int): Float {
    when (type) {
        Type.SOLID -> return actualHeight.toFloat()
        Type.DEGREE_DOWN_UP -> return 0f
        Type.DEGREE_UP_DOWN -> return actualHeight.toFloat()
        Type.DEGREE_LEFT_RIGHT, Type.DEGREE_RIGHT_LEFT -> return actualHeight / 2.0f
        else -> {}
    }
    return (-1).toFloat()
}

The type of the drawable is DEGREE_UP_DOWN
This is how I'm using the drawable:
val bg = GradientShading(Shading.Type.DEGREE_UP_DOWN, topColor, bottomColor)

LazyColumn(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            .clipToBounds()
            .drawBehind {
                drawIntoCanvas { bg.getDrawable().draw(it.nativeCanvas) }
            },
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
    )

What is wrong in the code?
THis is the working java version of the code, which is apparently exactly the same:
@Override
    public Drawable getDrawable() {
        ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory sf = new ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory() {
            @Override
            public Shader resize(int width, int height) {
                LinearGradient lg = new LinearGradient(startX(width), startY(height), endX(width), endY(height), new int[] {
                        color1 , color2 },
                        null, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
                 return lg;
            }
        };      
        PaintDrawable p = new PaintDrawable();
        p.setShape(new RectShape());
        p.setShaderFactory(sf);
        return (Drawable)p;
    }

float startX(int actualWidth) {         
        switch (this.type) {
        case SOLID:
            return 0;
        case DEGREE_DOWN_UP:
        case DEGREE_UP_DOWN:
            return actualWidth/2.0f;
        case DEGREE_LEFT_RIGHT:
            return 0.0f;
        case DEGREE_RIGHT_LEFT:
            return actualWidth;
        }
        
        return -1;
    }
    
    float startY(int actualHeight){     
        switch (this.type) {
        case SOLID:
            return 0;
        case DEGREE_DOWN_UP:
            return actualHeight;
        case DEGREE_LEFT_RIGHT:
        case DEGREE_RIGHT_LEFT:
            return actualHeight/2.0f;
        case DEGREE_UP_DOWN:
            return 0;
        }
        
        return -1;      
    }
    
    float endX(int actualWidth){        
        switch (this.type) {
        case SOLID:
            return actualWidth;
        case DEGREE_DOWN_UP:
        case DEGREE_UP_DOWN:
            return actualWidth/2.0f;
        case DEGREE_LEFT_RIGHT:
            return actualWidth;
        case DEGREE_RIGHT_LEFT:
            return 0;
        }       
        return -1;          
    }
    
    float endY(int actualHeight){       
        switch (this.type) {
        case SOLID:
            return actualHeight;
        case DEGREE_DOWN_UP:
            return 0;
        case DEGREE_UP_DOWN:
            return actualHeight;
        case DEGREE_LEFT_RIGHT:
        case DEGREE_RIGHT_LEFT:
            return actualHeight/2.0f;
        }       
        return -1;      
    }


Are you setting the Drawable's bounds somewhere? They're all zeroes by default. Btw, this one kinda works by accident, since they're ignoring the bounds in their draw. GradientDrawable relies on the bounds, though, to calculate its gradient.

PaintDrawable, I meant, relies on the bounds for the shader calculations.

Btw, at this point, it's probably the same amount of work to just translate it into proper Compose gradients and ditch the Drawable.

"after migrating the code to kotlin and compose" -- there does not appear to be any Compose-related code here. You might want to post how you are using this code and your Java version for comparison.

As @MikeM. rightly noted, I didn't set bounds for the drawable, so it is my bad that your Drawable is not working. I've modified my previous answer (you are intrested in drawIntoCanvas block), please check if it works now.

@CommonsWare Jan Itor Mike M. I attached how I'm using the code and also the java version of the code

@NullPointerException Check the updated version of this answer. You need to set drawable.bounds before calling drawable.draw. So if you remember your drawable like val drawable by remember { bg.getDrawable() } then call drawable.bounds = it.nativeCanvas.clipBounds before drawable.draw(it.nativeCanvas)

@JanItor thank you but I added that drawable.bounds = it.nativeCanvas.clipBounds and the drawable is not visible. I think something is broken in my way of generating that drawable. Did you see anything wrong?

@NullPointerException I posted how it worked for me with my approximation of GradientShading class implementation.

Assign nativeCanvas.clipBounds to drawable.bounds before calling drawable.draw like so:
val drawable = remember { GradientShading(Color.BLUE, Color.MAGENTA).getDrawable() }

LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth()
    .clipToBounds()
    .drawBehind {
        drawIntoCanvas { canvas ->
            drawable.bounds = canvas.nativeCanvas.clipBounds
            drawable.draw(canvas.nativeCanvas)
        }
    }
) {
    items(10) { Text("Item $it") }
}

My GradientShading class reconstruction for DEGREE_UP_DOWN (getDrawable method is the same):
private class GradientShading(val color1: Int, val color2: Int) {
    fun getDrawable(): Drawable {
        val sf: ShaderFactory = object : ShaderFactory() {
            override fun resize(width: Int, height: Int): Shader {
                return LinearGradient(
                    startX(width), startY(height), endX(width), endY(height), intArrayOf(
                        color1, color2
                    ),
                    null, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR
                )
            }
        }
        val p = PaintDrawable()
        p.shape = RectShape()
        p.shaderFactory = sf
        return p
    }

    fun startX(actualWidth: Int): Float {
        return actualWidth / 2.0f
    }

    fun startY(actualHeight: Int): Float {
        return 0f
    }

    fun endX(actualWidth: Int): Float {
        return actualWidth / 2.0f
    }

    fun endY(actualHeight: Int): Float {
        return actualHeight.toFloat()
    }
}

Result:


Wonderful Jan, thanks to you I found my error. I was calling bg.getDrawable().bounds and bg.getDrawable().draw in the drawIntoCanvas lambda, and for some reason it was generating the empty drawable. After extracting the getDrawable() call outside the lambda like you, and calling it only one time, it started working.

Just one question more. Why you put the drawable generation inside a  " = remember { }  " block? If you wanna keep it between recompositions for some reason, shouldn't be inside a remember mutablestate of?


I don't see why shouldn't we save the Drawable, I reckon it is cheaper that creating new ShaderFactory and PaintDrawable every recomposition. 2) We need a State when there is a composable that needs to be updated when the State changes. In this case LazyColumn updates don't depend on the Drawable. On the opposite, we update its bounds when LazyColumn updates or just needs to redraw. @NullPointerException

